# How to use RegCreateKeyEx?

Tags: c++, registrykey

I have a question about using `RegCreateKeyEx` in C++.
When I'm trying to create a key under HKLM - it does not work,
but other situation(creating the key at the HKCU) - it does work well (can create key).

My OS is win7 x86 - does it matter when using `RegCreateKeyEx`?

The code I'm running is the following:

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    HKEY hKey;
    LONG result = 0;
    char filename[] = "C:\test.jpg";
    char *path = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\test";

    if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hKey, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        printf("1. success \n"); // ← doesn`t work 
    else printf("fail\n");

    if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Console\papadaks", 0, NULL,       
            REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hKey, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        printf("2. success \n");  // ← works well 
    else printf("fail\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Several issues here: Please use a websearch to locate example code. "doesn't work" is not a sufficient description of the problem. Code is not formatted consistently. `"C:\test.jpg"` is a string literal containing a tab. What error exactly do the according functions signal, check their documentation how to determine further info on the error.

Comment: To start, [read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and pay special attention the access rights and virtualization sections.  Then, use [FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get an actual description of why it is failing.  It could be an incorrect parameter, it could be a security problem, you don't know because you don't check.

Comment: You might also read through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146666/access-to-hklm-registry-branch-on-win-7-from-within-application  It basically says you're going to have problems writing to HKLM unless you're an elevated process.

Comment: When it fails, what does GetLastError() return? Can you search for that error code in winerror.h (Windows SDK header file that defines all the error codes)?

Answer (score 3):

You will almost certainly be getting error 5 (access denied), because even if you are an administrator on that machine, for NT6 variants under UAC you would need to be elevated. Just because you're logged in under an admin account doesn't mean you have *actual* admin rights, thanks to the wonder that is UAC. This is actually a *good* thing.

You could test this hypothesis by temporarily modifying the security on the HKLM registry key you're creating under to allow everyone write capability (remember to set it back afterwards). Your code would then work... and your system would be slightly less secure.

The appropriate approach is to give your app a manifest that marks it as requiring elevation, so the user either has to acknowledge that the change is permitted (if they're an admin) or go and find someone actually *is* an admin to enter the password.